# proof by induction $2^n \leq 2^{n+1}-2^{n−1}-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

My question is prove by induction  for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $2^n \leq 2 ^{n+1}-2^{n−1}-1$

My proof

$1+2+3+4+....+2^n \leq 2^{n+1}-2^{n−1}-1$

Assume $n=1$,$1 ≤ 2$

Induction step

Assume statement is true for $n=k$, show true for $n=k + 1$

$1+2+3+4+....+2^k+2^k+1 ≤ 2 ^{k+1} ​​ −2^{k−1} ​​ - 1$

$2^{k+1} - 2^{k-1} -1 + 2^{k+1} ≤  2^{k+1} - 2^{k-1} -1$

$4^{k+1} -2^{k-1} -1 ≤  2^{k+1} - 2^{k-1} -1$

I do not know how to proceed from here, and i am confused because it seems to me this is not true.

Comment: Hi Rohan, it is really hard to read what you wrote in the first place, I edited it a bit, although I am not sure whether it is now that what you wanted to write down, the best would be, if you find my edit to be wrong, to add some of the brackets on your own or let me know what to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that $n=1$ we have $$2 \leq 2^2 - 2^0 - 1 \iff 2 \leq 2$$ which is true. Now, assuming that $$2^k \leq 2^{k+1} - 2^{k-1} - 1$$ holds. We proceed by multiplying our inductive hypothesis above by $2$ to get $$2 \cdot 2^{k} \leq 2(2^{k+1} - 2^{k-1} - 1)$$ Which simplifies to $$2^{k+1} \leq 2^{k+2} - 2^{k} - 2 \leq 2^{k+2} - 2^{k} - 1$$

So we get by transitivity that $$2^{k+1} \leq 2^{k+1 + 1} - 2^{k + 1 -1} - 1$$

So your statement is true by the principle of Mathematical Induction.

Comment: Why do you assume it is true for n=2. I thought you just assume it is true for n=1 then make n=k, then prove n=k+1.

Comment: I didn't assume it was true for $n=2$... I did exactly what you said...

Comment: But wouldn't you assume that now that it works for the case n=1 which is true, and assuming it holds we go on to assuming n=k, then n= k+1.

Comment: Exactly. I showed it held for $n=1$. What happens when you replace $n=1$ into your equation? What do you get? Then I assumed it held for $n=k$ and then showed it held for $n=k+1$.

Comment: Ohhhh n=1 and n=k are the same (1) so n = k+1 would be 2. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, we could prove it directly without induction:
\begin{align*}
2^{n + 1} - 2^{n - 1} - 1
&= (2^n + 2^n) - 2^{n - 1} - 1 \\
&= 2^n + (2^{n - 1} + 2^{n - 1}) - 2^{n - 1} - 1 \\
&= 2^n + 2^{n - 1} - 1 \\
&\geq 2^n + 2^{1 - 1} - 1 &\text{since } n \in \mathbb N \implies n \geq 1 \\
&= 2^n
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

since 
$$
2^{n+1} = 2^n + 2^n
$$
and
$$
2^n - 2^{n-1} = 2^{n-1}
$$
your statement, simplified, requires that:
$$
2^{n-1} \ge 1
$$
clearly this is true for $n=1$...

Comment: But, bizarrely, a proof by induction was required.

Comment: my last statement was the first step of an inductive proof. i thought it right to let OP derive the inductive step ;-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't read it carefully!