# Proving the inequality $2^n ≤2^{n+1}−2^{n−1}−1$

Tags: inequality

I've tried multiplying each side by $2^n$, factoring out a 2, but I find myself going in a circle. What's the best way to solve this?

$2^n ≤2^{n+1}−2^{n−1}−1$.   For all integers n

Comment: Hint:  try induction.

Comment: Subtract $2^n$ from both sides... (Hint: $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n$)

Comment: Divide both sides by $2^n$.

Comment: Base-$2$ hint: $$110001\leq 1000000  $$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1550380/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1997076/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1368099/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1716073/42969. – All found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%242%5En%20%5Cle%202%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%20-%202%5E%7Bn-1%7D%20-1%24&p=1)

Answer (score 3):

Hint. I guess that $n\geq 1$. Let $x=2^{n-1}$ then show that $2x\leq 4x-x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(3k+2)/(2)\leq 2k$$.  for all $k>0$ Check by PMI(principal of mathematical induction)
Now,$ (3k/2) + 1 \leq 2k$
  $  k + k/2 + 1 \leq2k$

Now take $k= 2^n$

$2^n +2^{n-1} +1 \leq2*2^n$
 i.e   $2^n \leq 2^{n+1} - 2^{n-1} - 1$

Answer (score 0):

For $n$ integer $$2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1=4\cdot2^{n-1}-2^{n-1}-1=3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1=2^n+2^{n-1}-1$$
Then $2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1\ge 2^{n}\iff2^{n-1}\ge 1\iff n\ge 1$.

Comment: $n \ge 1$, not $n \ge 0$. It is false for $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
2^n = 2\cdot 2^{n-1} \le 3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1 =2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

As abiessu wrote, since $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n$,
this is
$0\le 2^n-2^{n-1}-1
=2^{n-1}-1
$
which is true for
$n \ge 1$.

The inequality is strict
for $n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

It's$$2\cdot2^{n-1}\leq4\cdot2^{n-1}-2^{n-1}-1$$ or
$$2^{n-1}\geq1.$$
Done!